# Multiplication partitioning into k distinct elements

Tags: combinatorics, factoring, integer-partitions

Let's say I have a list with the prime factors of a number $n$ and their corresponding exponents. Is there a formula to calculate how many multiplications with $k$ distinct factors of $n$ are possible? For example, $12 = 2^2 \times 3$, so $F(12,2)$ would be:

$[2,6][3,4][1,12] = 3$

Note that the order of each set of factors does not matter. I have a feeling I only need the exponents of each prime factor, but I'm at a loss on how to actually proceed.

Comment: Trying to cheat on project euler? :)

Comment: @RenéG, after two days of thinking about it for hours I had no option but to give up, unfortunately, haha.

Comment: Ya that's how I found your question in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is a straightforward application of the Polya Enumeration
Theorem and very similar to the problem discussed at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099238/).

**Remark.** What follows below does permit repeated factors,
the formula for distinct factors is at the end.

Recall  the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(S_n)$ of
the multiset operator $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod} \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{MSET}_{=n}$ on $n$ slots, which is
$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n a_l Z(S_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

We have for example,
$$Z(S_3) = 1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/2\,a_{{2}}a_{{1}}+1/3\,a_{{3}}$$
and
$$Z(S_4) = 1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}+1/4\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}
+1/3\,a_{{3}}a_{{1}}+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}+1/4\,a_{{4}}.$$

Suppose the prime factorization of $n$ is given by
$$n=\prod_p p^v.$$

Applying PET it now follows almost by inspection that the
desired count is given by the term
$$F(n, k) = \left[\prod_p X_p^v\right]
Z(S_k)\left(\prod_p \frac{1}{1-X_p}\right)$$
where the square bracket denotes coefficient extraction 
of formal power series.

As an  example of what  these substituted cycle indices  look like
consider
$$Z(S_3)\left(\frac{1}{1-X_1}\frac{1}{1-X_2}\frac{1}{1-X_3}\right)
\\ = 1/6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 1-X_{{1}} \right) ^{3} 
\left( 1-X_{{2}} \right) ^{3}\left( 1-X_{{3}} \right) ^{3}}}
\\+1/2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{X_{{1}}}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( -{X_{{2}}}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( -{X_{{3}}}^{2}+1 \right)
 \left( 1-X_{{1}} \right)  \left( 1-X_{{2}} \right)  
\left( 1-X_{{3}} \right) }}
\\+1/3\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{X_{{1}}}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( -{X_{{2
}}}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( -{X_{{3}}}^{3}+1 \right) }}.$$

It  should be  clear  that  coefficient extraction  here  is fast  and
efficient using the Newton binomial series which says that
$$[Q^{\mu k}] \left(\frac{1}{1-Q^\mu}\right)^\nu
= {k+\nu-1\choose \nu-1}.$$

We get for $F(n,1)$ the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,\ldots$$
which is as it ought to be.

For $F(n,2)$ we get the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A038548](https://oeis.org/A038548).

As another example consider $F(n,4)$ which yields
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A21320](https://oeis.org/A218320)
where the above calculation is confirmed.

As a last example consider $F(n,5)$ which yields starting at $n=20$
$$4, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 7, 2, 2, 2, 9, 1, 2, 2,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A252665](https://oeis.org/A252665).

The  following   Maple  code  implements this cycle index computation.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

F :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local v, q, sind, res;

    v := op(2, ifactors(n));

    sind :=
    pet_varinto_cind(mul(1/(1-cat(`X`, q)), q=1..nops(v)),
                     pet_cycleind_symm(k));

    res := sind;
    for q to nops(v) do
        res := coeftayl(res, cat(`X`, q)=0, v[q][2]);
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**Addendum.** For distinct factors the formula is
$$G(n, k) = \left[\prod_p X_p^v\right]
Z(P_k)\left(\prod_p \frac{1}{1-X_p}\right)$$
where the square bracket denotes coefficient extraction 
of formal power series and $Z(P_n)$ is the cycle index of the 
set operator $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod} \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}_{=n}$ which was also used in the linked-to
computation from above.

Starting at $n=20$ we get for $G(n,3)$ the sequence
$$2, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A088434](https://oeis.org/A088434).

Starting at $n=120$ we get for $G(n,4)$ the sequence
$$8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,\ldots$$

The Maple code for $G(n,k)$ is as follows.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l-1)*a[l]*pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

# duplicate code omitted

G :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local v, q, sind, res;

    v := op(2, ifactors(n));

    sind :=
    pet_varinto_cind(mul(1/(1-cat(`X`, q)), q=1..nops(v)),
                     pet_cycleind_set(k));

    res := sind;
    for q to nops(v) do
        res := coeftayl(res, cat(`X`, q)=0, v[q][2]);
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**Addendum.**  Observe that  we  can easily  compute $$G(n,5)$$  where
$$n=2^{50}\times 3^{20} \times 5^{10}$$  which has $11781$ divisors so
that    the    brute    force    method   would    have    to    check
$$1889560697901637761$$  five-tuples,  which  is  not  feasible.   The
answer is $$27879304592.$$

Comment: Slightly overwhelming but I will study the code to see if I can translate it into another language, a million thanks!

Comment: Being a Linux user and programmer I strongly encourage translating these MAPLE routines for [PET computations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) and making them available for anyone to use. (The link has contributions from a number of users.)

Comment: I will certainly upvote a functional contribution in another language that would then confirm the results from the above post assuming I have not made any mistakes.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It seems this algorithm can compute large values of n but it becomes inefficient when k increases. For example, (10!,30) hogs a lot of memory and takes too long to finish. Are there any particular optimizations that could be made to calculate when k = 30 and n is a factorial? I'm assuming that, since calculating the divisors of a factorial is trivial, there's a significant speed improvement that can be made.

Comment: The factorization is not a determining factor here, rather it is the coefficient extraction from the $5604$ terms in the cycle index $Z(P_{30})$. Fine-tuning this would appear to be a thesis type project involving a considerable effort of optimization and innovative coding.

Comment: Then I'm approaching my particular problem in the wrong way. Still though, your answer was really informative and helped me learn some more properties of combinatorics, so once again thank you!

Comment: What's the complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score -2):

Any number in prime factorization would look like:

N = X_1^a * X_2^b * X_3^c * ... where X_1, X_2, X_3, ... are its prime factors

Notice that all powers of X_1 will be factors of N. So we can vary a from 0 through 1, 2, 3, ... to a. i.e. a can have a+1 values and for all these, X_1^a will be a factor. Similarly X_2 and X_3 and so on will be factors from 0 to b+1 and from 0 to c+1 etc. Also, we can choose X_1, X_2, X_3 etc. simultaneously. So, the total factors of N should be (a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)*....

Since you want only pairs and any one factor of N can pair up with exactly one other factor to give N on multiplication, you simply divide number of factors by 2 and you have

[(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)....]/2

Comment: I think I understand the basic idea so maybe I'm applying it wrong, but wouldn't this approach for higher of k? For example, $144 = 2^4 \times 3^2$, so $F(144,4) = [(4+1)\times(2+1)] / 4 = 15 / 4 = 4,25$, which obviously since $F(144,4) = [1,2,4,18] [1,2,8,9] [1,2,3,24] [1,2,6,12] [1,3,4,12] [1,3,6,8] [2,3,4,6] = 7$

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand. What do you mean by 'would it work for higher values of k'? What is k?

Comment: I think I expressed myself wrong in the title. F(n,k) is the amount of ways in which you can express n as the product of k distinct numbers.

Answer (score -3):

Yes! From a number theoretical perspective, this is known as the divisor function. Or, even more generally, $\sigma_k (n)$ where the sigma function denotes the sum of all divisors of an integer to the power $k$. If we set $k=0$ we see that this is exactly the same as counting all possible divisors of this integer.

The general form of the divisor function (sometimes denoted $d(n)$) is as follows:

$$\prod_{p^\alpha || n} (\alpha +1)$$ where $p^\alpha || n$ means that $p^\alpha |n$ but $p^{\alpha +1}$ does not. Also, p denotes a prime divisor. Also, if the notation is getting to you, just thinking of it as factorizing an integer, and then taking the product of 1 more than all the exponents of each divisor. (Do an example!)

Comment: I think I didn't express myself as clear as I should have. The formula you gave, if I'm correct, shows all the ways in which you can express a number as a product of its divisors, right?

However, what I'm looking for is in how many ways can a number be represented as the product of k distinct divisors. So F(144,4) would be the same as asking "How many unique sets (a,b,c,d) where a * b * c * d = 144 are there?" Remembering that permutations of the same set do not count and each element only appears once in each set.