# Number of factorizations of distinct factors

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ an integer with $p_i$ prime and $e_i \in \mathbb N$. The prime factorization can assumed to be *known*, i.e., we already know $p_1, \dotsc, p_k$ and $e_1, \dotsc e_k$.

Is it possible to find the number of factorizations of length $m$ of the form

$n = n_1 \cdot n_2 \dotsm n_m$ such that $n_1 < n_2 < \dotsb < n_m$ other than brute forcing?

(That means two factorizations that are just a rearrangement of each other are counted as the same one, e.g. $1 \times 2 \times 3$ is considered the same  as $1 \times 3 \times 2$, so we only count those in ascending order.)

Example: For the number $n = 12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ we have following factorizations with the factors in ascending order:

For $m=1$ we have one:

- $12$

For $m=2$ we have three:

- $1 \times 12$
- $2 \times 6$
- $3 \times 4$

For $m=3$ we have two:

- $1 \times 2 \times 6$
- $1 \times 3 \times 4$

Comment: If you are at all interested in an easier problem you can visit Sloane's OEIS A251683 and A074206.  These sequences count the number of ordered facorizations of n.  There are some references that might be beneficial.

Comment: If all $e_i = 1$, this is the number of ways to partition an $m$ set into $k$ parts, i.e., Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: The number of factorizations of distinct factors that you are interested, is it different from the number $f(n, k)$ of ordered $k$-factorizations of $n$ found by MacMahon, i.e.
$$f(n,m) = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^i \binom{m}{i}\prod_{j=1}^{k}{\binom{e_j+m-i-1}{e_j}}}$$

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250364/) may prove useful as regards the theoretical aspects of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  me present  a proof  of the  first special  case (product  of $k$
distinct primes) by @martin, which is a nice result that can be proved
by Polya enumeration.

I will assume the reader  has consulted and understood the material at
the following
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250364/) 
which I will not duplicate here.

Using the notation from the link  with $q$ being the number of factors
in  the partition  we  obtain  by the  Polya  Enumeration Theorem  the
following formula:

$$G(k, q) = \left[\prod_p X_p\right]
Z(P_q)\left(\prod_p (1+X_p)\right)
\quad\text{where}\quad n=\prod_p p^v$$

with all  $v=1$ and we have  $k$ distinct primes in  the product. Here
the  square bracket  denotes  coefficient extraction  of formal  power
series  and  $Z(P_q)$   is  the  cycle  index  of   the  set  operator
$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod} \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}_{=q}$ which  was also used in  the linked-to computation from above.

Now recall the OGF of the set operator which is
$$Z(P_q) = [z^q]
\exp\left(a_1 z - a_2 \frac{z^2}{2}
+ a_3 \frac{z^3}{3}
- a_4 \frac{z^4}{4}
+\cdots \right).$$

Observe that on substituting into the cycle index we let
$$a_m = \prod_p (1+X_p^m).$$

But the  degree of  $X_p$ in the  coefficient being extracted  is one,
which means that  from the $a_m$ with $m\ge 2$  only the constant term
contributes, which is one.

This gives the formula

$$G(k, q) = \left[\prod_p X_p\right] [z^q]
\exp\left(z\prod_p (1+X_p) 
- \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} - \frac{z^4}{4} + \cdots\right)$$

which is
$$G(k, q) = \left[\prod_p X_p\right] [z^q]
\exp\left(z\left(-1+\prod_p (1+X_p)\right) + \log(1+z)\right)
\\ = \left[\prod_p X_p\right] [z^q] (1+z) 
\exp\left(z\left(-1+\prod_p (1+X_p)\right)\right)
\\ = \left[\prod_p X_p\right]
\left(\frac{1}{q!} \left(-1+\prod_p (1+X_p)\right)^q
+ \frac{1}{(q-1)!} \left(-1+\prod_p (1+X_p)\right)^{q-1}\right).$$

Doing coefficient extraction on the first term
we find
$$\left[\prod_p X_p\right]
\frac{1}{q!} \sum_{m=0}^q {q\choose m} (-1)^{q-m}
\prod_p (1+X_p)^m.$$

Only the terms with $X_p$ raised to the power one contribute
and we get for the first term
$$\frac{1}{q!} \sum_{m=0}^q {q\choose m} (-1)^{q-m} m^k
= {k\brace q}.$$

The second  term is  similar and therefore  the answer to  the special
case of a product of $k$ primes is

$${k\brace q} + {k\brace q-1}.$$

Now  that   we  have   this  we  can   easily  give   a  combinatorial
interpretation. The first term represents the case where we divide the
$k$ prime factors into $q$  non-empty sets which correspond to the $q$
distinct  factors of  the multiplicative  partition with  none  of the
factors being one. (With the $k$ primes being distinct the products of
the  elements of these  sets are  necessarily distinct.)   This almost
completes  the  count except  we  have  not  accounted for  partitions
containing  one as  a factor.  That leaves  $q-1$ distinct  factors to
choose according to the same procedure as before, done.

**Remark.** Using the OGF of the Stirling numbers of the second kind
which is
$${n\brace k} = [z^n] \prod_{r=1}^k \frac{z}{1-rz}$$

we get the generating function
$$\prod_{r=1}^q \frac{z}{1-rz}+
\prod_{r=1}^{q-1} \frac{z}{1-rz}
= \left(1+\frac{z}{1-qz}\right) \prod_{r=1}^{q-1} \frac{z}{1-rz}
\\ = \frac{1-(q-1)z}{1-qz}  \prod_{r=1}^{q-1} \frac{z}{1-rz}.$$

Comment: this looks great! Thanks for posting the answer - there is loads to learn from it - fantastic :) - Will no doubt award you the bounty , unless in the very unlikely event that someone comes up with a solution to the general case (but I for one can make neither head nor tail of the the sequences that arise when $e^i, i\neq 1$).

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. I enjoyed the Eureka effect when I saw the Stirling numbers.

Answer (score 5):

**Special cases**

For $n = p_i p_2 \cdots p_k$, *(all with exponent $1$)*, the multiplicative partitions $m_1, m_2,\dots, m_{k+1}$ are given by the coefficients of the expanded series $$f(x,k)=\dfrac{1-(k-1) x}{\prod _{n=1}^k (1-n x)}$$ where the $m$th partition of $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ is give by the $(k-m+2)$th coefficient.

```
f[k_] := (1 - (k - 1) x)/Product[1 - n x, {n, 1, k}]
g[a_, b_] := CoefficientList[Series[f@b, {x, 0, b + a}], x][[a - b + 2]]
h[n_] := g[n, #] & /@ Range[n + 1]

h[#] & /@ Range@6
```

gives

\begin{array}{c}
1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 4 & 4 & 1\\
1 & 8 & 13 & 7 & 1\\
1 & 16 & 40 & 35 & 11 & 1\\
1 & 32 & 121 & 155 & 80 & 16 & 1\\
\end{array}

*eg* $30$ has partitions of length $m_1=1,\ m_2=4,\ m_3=4,\ m_4=1$:

$m_1=1$:

- $30$

$m_2=4$:

- $1 \times 30$
- $2 \times 15$
- $3 \times 10$
- $5 \times 6$

$m_3=4$:

- $1 \times 2 \times 15$
- $1 \times 3 \times 10$
- $1 \times 5 \times 6$
- $2 \times 3 \times 5$

$m_4=1$:

- $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 5$

---

The multiplicative partitions $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_{\left\lfloor \sqrt{2 (k+1)}+1/2\right\rfloor}$ for $p^k$ (where $p$ is prime) are given by the coefficients of the expanded series  $$f_1(x,k)=\dfrac{1}{\prod _{n=1}^k (1-x^n)}$$ where the $m$th partition is give by the $(m+ 1 - k(k- 1)/2)$th coefficient.

```
f1[k_] := 1/Product[(1 - x^n), {n, 1, k}]
g1[a_, b_] := CoefficientList[Series[f1@b, {x, 0, b + a}], x][[1 - b (b - 1)/2 + a]]
h1[n_] := g1[n, #] & /@ Range@Floor[Sqrt[2 (n + 1)] + 1/2]

h1[#] & /@ Range@6
```

gives

\begin{array}{c}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1\\
\end{array}

*eg* $512$ has partitions of length $m_1=1,\ m_2=5,\ m_3=7,\ m_4=3$.

$m_1=1$:

- $512$

$m_2=5$:

- $1 \times 512$
- $2 \times 256$
- $4 \times 128$
- $8 \times 64$
- $16 \times 32$

$m_3=7$:

- $1 \times 2 \times 256$
- $1 \times 4 \times 128$
- $1 \times 8 \times 64$
- $1 \times 16 \times 32$
- $2 \times 4 \times 64$
- $2 \times 8 \times 32$
- $4 \times 8 \times 16$

$m_4=3$:

- $1 \times 2 \times 4 \times 64$
- $1 \times 2 \times 8 \times 32$
- $1 \times 4 \times 8 \times 16$

---

It would be nice to find a generalised solution for any $p_i^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, but not sure whether this is easiliy attainable.

Comment: Let me observe that the second special case counts partitions into distinct parts. We immediately obtain the expression $$[z^k][y^q] \prod_{m=0}^k (1+yz^m)$$ which is [OEIS A00009](http://oeis.org/A000009).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel brilliant again - thanks :) ... I wonder if the secret to the more complex cases is bound up in this somewhere?...

Comment: It gets complicated quickly as seen e.g. at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251256/).