# Write as a product of integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

My question is that in how many ways can $10,000!$ be written as the product of $30$ distinct positive integers. My question is similar to this question:
[In how many ways can $1000000$ be expressed as a product of five distinct positive integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251256/in-how-many-ways-can-1000000-be-expressed-as-a-product-of-five-distinct-positi) but mine is much larger.

Comment: There are $K=1229$ primes $\leq N:=10\,000$. For each such prime $p$ compute $m=\lfloor N/p\rfloor+\lfloor N/p^2\rfloor+\ldots$ (a finite sum). This $m$ is the exponent of $p$  in $N!$. In this way you get an array ${\bf m}=(m_k)_{1\leq k\leq K}$. Now you have to count solutions of  $\sum_{i=1}^{30}{\bf x}_i ={\bf m}$ satisfying certain constraints.

Comment: Why the above should not be a question about mathematics is beyond me. It's again so that certain "Oberlehrers" didn't see a (maybe  approximate) solution right away; so they decided to close the question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Hmmm. So would the only way to calculate this be with a computer program? If so, I'm not used to programming, how would I program this?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Can we calculate this using wolfram alpha? Can you give a link if possible? I'm not very familiar with stars and bars and its application to this problem