# What is the number of ways of distributing '$n$' identical items among '$r$' identical baskets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have  seen explanations for distribution among '$r$' groups as opposed to '$r$' identical groups(example: if $12$ eggs are to be distributed among $4$ baskets such that the baskets are not numbered). I know that it cannot be done by finding the number of possible whole number solutions for these $4$ baskets$[(12+4-1)C(4-1)]$, which gives the answer when the baskets are numbered, and then dividing by 4! to "adjust" for the "identical" baskets(as there would also be distributions such as $2,2,3,5; 2,3,2,5; 2,2,2,6$). All this leads me to wonder if there is a single working formula(without the need of step-by-step calculation) for the same.

Comment: Do you know generating functions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Answer (score 0):

Using the Polya Enumeration Theorem the closed form is given by

$$[z^n] Z(S_r)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$

where $Z(S_r)$ is  the cycle index of the symmetric  group. This cycle
index  is   known  in   species  theory   as  the   multiset  operator
$\mathfrak{M}_{=r}.$

Recall the  recurrence by Lovasz for  the cycle index $Z(S_r)$  of the
set operator $\mathfrak{M}_{=r}$ on $r$ slots, which is

$$Z(S_r) = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{l=1}^r a_l Z(S_{r-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$
This recurrence lets us calculate the cycle index $Z(S_r)$ very easily.

For example when $r=5$ the cycle index is
$$Z(S_5) = 
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}}{120}}+1/12\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{3}}
{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}
\\+1/4\,a_{{4}}a_{{1}}+1/6\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}+1/5\,a_{{5}}$$

and the generating function becomes

$${\frac {1}{120\, \left( 1-z \right) ^{5}}}
+1/12\,{\frac {1}{ \left(-{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}
+1/6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{2}}}
\\+1/8\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 1-z \right)  \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
+1/4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{4}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) }}
+1/6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right) }}
\\+1/5\, \left( -{z}^{5}+1 \right) ^{-1}.$$

which gives the sequence

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 18, 23, 30, 37, 47, 57, 70, 84, 101, 
\\ 119, 141, 164, 192, \ldots$$

that points to [OEIS A001401](https://oeis.org/A001401) which looks to
be a match. Here we have assumed that empty bins are admissible.

This   [MSE   link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251256/)
shows how  one might go about  producing a closed form  expression for
the coefficients of this type of generating function. Furthermore this
[MSE       link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618420/)
presents an algorithm for computing these closed forms.

There is some Maple code to help explore these data.

```
pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;
```