# Number of unordered factorizations into $k$ distinct parts

Tags: recurrence-relations, prime-factorization

Let $H_d(n)$ denote the number of distinct ordered factorizations of $n$ and $H_d(n,k)$ the number of ordered factorizations of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts. We have the following recurrence:
$$H_d(n,k+1) = k! \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j}{(k-j)!} \sum_{d,d|n} H_d(n/d, k-j),$$
where the inside sum is taken over all $d$ such that $d|n$ and for $d \geq 2$, $d$ is a ($j+1$)-st power.
We then obtain $H_d(n)$ by summing over the $k$: $H_d(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n H_d(n,k)$.

Let $P_d(n,k)$ be the number of unordered factorizations into $k$ distinct parts. We know that $H_d(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k! P_d(n,k)$ and it turns out that $H_d(n,k) = k! P_d(n,k)$ which lead to
$$P_d(n,k) = \frac{H_d(n,k)}{k!}.$$

Since $H_d(n,k)$ contains a product by $k!$, I thought $P_d(n,k)$ could be simplified but I do not know how to proceed due to the use of $k$ in the recursive call.

Any help to get a nice formula for $P_d(n,k)$ would be appreciated!

Comment: As a start, for a fixed prime $p$, can you get a formula for $P_d(p^r,k)$ as a function of $r$?

Comment: @GregMartin $P_d(p^r,k)=Q(r,k)$ where $Q(n,k)$ denote the number of ways of partitioning $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts. The formula is given by the equation 19 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html).

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250364/) may prove useful reading.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I am aware of this answer but thought that a "nicer" formula could be deduced from $H_d$.