# Evaluating sums of the form $\sum_{i_d=1}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{i_2=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i_1=1}^{\infty}x^{i_1\cdot i_2\cdots i_d}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering if there is a way to evaluate or get a more useful expression for a sum of the following form:
$$\sum_{i_d=1}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{i_2=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i_1=1}^{\infty}x^{i_1\cdot i_2\cdots i_d},$$ where $|x|<1.$  For example, if $d=2$, then the sum is an example of a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) and the exponents that appear are essentially given by (up to some index shuffling) this [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C5%2C3&language=english&go=Search).  In this case it is not difficult to obtain $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{j}}{1-x^{j}},$$ which I can then evaluate for any $|x|<1.$

This can be viewed as summing over a $d$-dimensional non-negative integer lattice, so I've looked at things like "lattice sums" (tried to post a link here but not enough reputation points to post more than 2 links) but can't seem to find anything helpful there.

Even something for the case $d=3$ would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you can evaluate the remaining infinite sum in the $d=2$ case, I gather that reducing the multiple sum to a single infinite sum would already be sufficient progress.

Then you want to count the number $\pi_d(n)$ of ways in which a positive integer $n$ can be written as an ordered product of positive integers. Find the prime factorisation, $n=\prod_ip_i^{k_i}$, and independently distribute $k_i$ balls over $d$ bins for each $i$, for a total of $\pi_d(n)=\prod_i\binom{k_i+d-1}{d-1}$ ways. Then your sum is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\pi_d(n)x^n\;,
$$

the ordinary generating function for $\pi_d(n)$. Note that $\pi_d(n)$ is a multiplicative function, which allows you to calculate it without factorising.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473925, which addresses the slightly different problem of counting the number of ways $n$ can be expressed as a product of any number of factors $\ge2$.

Comment: If you write $x = \,\mathrm{e}^{-\beta}$, the problem resembles a usual statistical physics problem. The usual difficulty is to find the 'number of configurations ' that makes $i_{1}\ldots i_{d} = n$ for a given $n$ which we call the number of states ( your $\pi_{d}\left(n\right)$ ) and it's given by
$$
\sum_{i_{1} = 1}\ldots\sum_{i_{1} = 1}\delta_{n,\prod_{k = 1}^{d}i_{k}}
$$

It is usually the main task. Good luck.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I don't understand. That's precisely the problem that my answer intended to solve. Are you saying that it doesn't?

Comment: You are quite right and that's the good direction to follow.

I just want to highlight an analogy from Physics where it's a somehow current task and it's usually quite difficult. Fortunately, in Physics it's usual to look for the asymptotic behaviour ( 'for large $n$' ). It could be difficult too. I always follow your answers and they are always pretty fine and very professional. 

I'm sorry if I was misunderstood.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I see. Thanks for the kind words, sorry about the misunderstanding. My first name is Felix, too, by the way :-)

Comment: @joriki This is what I thought, thanks.  I suppose that there isn't much more simplifying that can be done.  I know that the Dirichlet g.f. for $\pi_d(n)$ is $\zeta^d(s)$, but I can't seem to find any nice expressions for the ordinary generating function of $pi_d(n)$....

Comment: @guest6168834605: If this is what you thought, it would have saved me a lot of time if you'd mentioned that in the question.